# How should I name my Laravel project if I want it to have multiple words?

Tags: php, laravel

When using `laravel new blog` and `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` to create a new project, it seems that the project name can not be made of multiple words with space between them. I assume that this means I'd have to use underscores, dashes or camel case, however, I am not sure if there's a preferred case.

If I wanted to name my project using 2 word - Laravel and Project, which of the following versions is the best one:

```
LaravelProject
Laravel-Project
Laravel_Project
```

Comment: In that case i think you should follow laravel package naming convention and that's second one.
laravel-project

Comment: It will be name of directory created. You can achieve that with putting name into quotes i.e. `laravel new "Laravel Project"` or escaping empty string `laravel new Laravel\ Project`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is the most used one **Laravel-Project-Name** for laravel packages, although in those cases they mostly use lower case.

It's only a matter of preference to you, for me it looks cleaner to name using **CamelCaseConvention**.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** use multiple words with spaces in between them. This is not a Laravel or Composer issue, but rather how spaces are handled in the command line interface.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/530578/how-to-write-the-path-of-a-folder-with-space-in-its-name

Write your folder/project name as `'folder name'` (surrounded with quotes) or `folder\ name` (escaped space character).